# Tell Nginx not to cache based on a response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx to serve MediaWiki, and I use FastCGI caching to avoid unnecessary PHP calls.

(In the MediaWiki `LocalSettings.php` file, I have `$wgUseCdn = true`; and in the Nginx config, I use `fastcgi_cache` and related config options.)

Problem is, many HTTP responses from MediaWiki/PHP (aka upstream) contain a `Vary` header with `User-Agent` in it. And since user agent strings are so detailed and variable, this probably makes Nginx needlessly cache a ton of identical copies of some pages and rarely ever give a new visitor a cached version.

I can give the Nginx FCGI cache a whole 12 GiB of space, and it fills it all up, but I suspect it's mostly junk due to this problem, and that only a fraction of the cache contents are actually useful.

I'd like to tell the Nginx FastCGI cache to **not** cache a response if the `Vary` response header sent back from the MediaWiki PHP code contains `User-Agent`.

(There are also lots of resources sent back from PHP which don't vary based on user-agent, and Nginx can still cache those.)

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
# In the http context:
map $sent_http_vary $fcgi_nocache {
  default 0;
  "~*user-agent" 1;
}

# In a location *.php context:
add-header X-Fcgi-Nocache $fcgi_nocache;
# Or, if it worked fine, to actually make the nocache take effect:
fastcgi_no_cache $fcgi_nocache;
```

This allows me to check the `X-Fcgi-Nocache` header received by my HTTP client (e.g. web browser) to see if the `map` directive does what I want, but the value is always `0` so I guess the `$sent_http_vary` variable doesn't work the way I hoped it would.

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but suddenly it's working.  Maybe I had typed `"*~user-agent"` instead of `"~*user-agent"` or maybe it was a similarly stupid typo, but currently it seems to be working as intended.

That being said, by suggestion of someone in the `#nginx` IRC channel on Libera, I've now also changed it to use the variable `$upstream_http_vary` instead of `$sent_http_vary`. This may be more reliable, although it seemed to be working with the `$sent_xyz` variant as well.

Also, I've noticed that MediaWiki either specifies no `Vary` header at all, or one that includes `User-Agent`, so there's actually no need for the `map` directive, although it's good to know that it's a possibility.

In short, simple solution:

```
# In location context, where fastcgi_pass and fastcgi_cache are specified:
fastcgi_no_cache $upstream_http_vary;
```

More refined solution, if needed, e.g. checking the `Vary` header for `User-Agent`:

```
# In http context, where fastcgi_cache_path is specified:
map $upstream_http_vary $fcgi_nocache {
  default 0;
  "~*user-agent" 1;
}
```

```
# In location context, where fastcgi_pass and fastcgi_cache specified:
fastcgi_no_cache $fcgi_nocache;
```